# Pandas: how to plot with custom colors and symbols

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I use colors that have a long name and custom markers in Pandas?

With standard colors I would do:

```
df.plot(style = 'ro')
```

but I cannot do:

```
df.plot(style = 'lightgreeno')
```

I tried:

```
df.plot(color = 'lightgreen', style = 'o')
```

but I get:

```
ValueError: Cannot pass 'style' string with a color symbol and 'color' keyword argument. Please use one or the other or pass 'style' without a color symbol
```

any ideas?

Comment: Hex values for the `color` kwarg aren't going to help when the problem is having the `color` and `style` kwargs together.

Answer (score 12):

`style` wraps `color` and `marker` and `linestyle` together. As soon as you specify one of those explicitly, you need to be explicit about any of them. An example from the `plot` documentation:

> plot(x, y, color='green', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',
>        markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12).

so in your line change `style` to `marker` :

```
df.plot(color = 'lightgreen', marker = 'o')
```